# Disconnected from the target VM

Tags: java, sockets, debugging, intellij-idea, virtual-machine

Sometimes when I press on the debug button in IntelliJ I receive the following and can't debug as a result. I wonder what could be wrong and how that can be fixed?

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:59089,suspend=y,server=n -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-doclet.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/htmlconverter.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Users/mona/IdeaProjects/testJ/out/production/testJ:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" PeakElementLog
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59089', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59089', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: That's the message you would see if the debugee VM exits.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably normal behavior. If you are experiencing an error such as an exception then you should also see a stack trace in there. If not, it is possible that you are catching and silently eating the exception.